# Access the property of an object within an object?

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom "brain" class that has a custom "recipe" object as one of it's properties.

The recipe class has four "ingredient" objects as properties.

If I try and do:

```
brain.myRecipe.ingredient1 = myIngredient;
self.displayLabel.text = brain.myRecipe.ingredient1.ingredientName;
```

The label is blank (although I get no errors)

but if I do

```
Ingredient * temp = myIngredient;
self.displayLabel.text = temp.ingredientName;
```

That one works...  Are you not able to drill down through properties like that with the dot operator?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the ingredient1 property a pointer? I'm a little rusty on my Obj-C syntax, it's been a while. I know the reason Ingredient * temp works is because you're setting a pointer to the object, so the compiler is asking "what is myIngredients.ingredientName's value?" when using temp.

Comment: Yes, ingredient1 property is a pointer to an Ingredient object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the dot operator.  Most likely one of those properties is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `brain` is not nil.

If not :

Check `myrecipe` and `ingredient1` properties ? Are they set on `retain` ?
**If not, put retain.**

Check `@synthesize` for both. Aren't there any type mistake so their name would not match the one set fo the properties and the ivars ?
**If there are mistakes (lokk ate upper/lowercases), correct.**

I also guess that `Ingredient` inherits from `NSObject` (at least) and have `[super init]` on the begining of its init method ?
**If not, do you class inherit NSObject, and init it first.**

If nothing works... then, just put some more code. How do you want us to solve your problem with such a little piece of code ?

You should have something like :

```
Brain : NSObject {
   MyReceipe* receipe;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyReceipe* receipe;



MyReceipe : NSObject {
   Ingredient* ingredient1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Ingredient* ingredient1;



Ingredient : NSObject {
   NSString* ingredientName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* ingredientName;
```

in all the .m, add `@synthsize the_property_name`

and an init method like

```
- (id) init {
   self = [super init];
   if (!self) return nil;

   self.the_ivar = nil; (or whatever you want)

   return self;
}
```

Comment: I think what he's trying to say is that he needs more information. =)

Comment: You just asked a bunch of questions about the object, that's all. Was being "humorous".

Comment: Yes, "myrecipe" is a property of the brain class and "ingredient1" is a property of recipe class.
the brain class synthesizes myrecipe, and recipe class synthesizes ingredient1.
ingredient1 is indeed a string
yes, Ingredient inherits from NSObject and has super init.  Also, brain is not nil

Comment: wait, ingredient1 is not a string,  that is an Ingredient object, which is a property of the myRecipe object.   ingredient1.ingredientName is an NSString however